# Prove an equality in probability

Tags: probability

I need help in proving the following equality:

> Let $g(x)$ be a measurable function, prove that $$E[E(Y|X)g(X)]=E(Yg(X)).$$
> Here $X, Y$ are random variables and $E$ stands for the expectation. (assume that all expectations exist)

I already know the law of total expectation, which is $E[E(X|Y)]=EX.$

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What can you say about $\mathsf{E}\left[Yg(X)\mid X\right]$?

Comment: I got it, nice hint, thanks so much.